# How to write constructor/assignment operator overloads for custom string types?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

```
struct ci_char_traits : public std::char_traits<char>
{
  static bool eq( char c1, char c2 ) { return toupper( c1 ) == toupper( c2 ); }
  static bool ne( char c1, char c2 ) { return toupper( c1 ) != toupper( c2 ); }
  static bool lt( char c1, char c2 ) { return toupper( c1 ) <  toupper( c2 ); }

  static int compare( const char* s1, const char* s2, size_t n );
  static const char* find( const char* s, int n, char a );
};

using ci_string = std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits>;
```

I'm working with this char_traits derivative which should help me dealing with case-insensitive string comparisons. It works perfectly fine when constructing ci_strings from character literals, however I'm often faced with the situation where I have one or two std::strings and would like to compare them case-insensitively.
Is there some way to write a custom constructor or assignment/conversion operator to convert from std::string to ci_string or is there no other possibility than to iterate the std::strings and call tolower on each character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct a `ci_string` from a `std::string`, you can use the constructor that takes an iterator range.  This will iterate through the `std::string` and store a copy of its characters into the `ci_string`:

```
std::string foo = "test";
ci_string bar(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

This will work for any `basic_string` specialization as long as the underlying type (`char` in this case) is the same.  You would not want to do this though with a `std::wstring`, as that uses `wchar_t`, which would give you an incorrect conversion.

Also, as pointed out in comments, you can also construct the `ci_string` using the constructor that takes a `const char*` and count:

```
std::string foo = "test";
ci_string bar(foo.c_str(), foo.length());
```

This has the advantage that you could not use any "string" that uses something other than `char` under the hood, like `std::wstring`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the constructor that takes a `char*` and a length as input: `ci_string bar(foo.c_str(), foo.size());` That would also prevent trying to construct a `ci_string` from a `std::wstring` since a `wchar_t*` cannot be assigned to a `char*`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point.  We don't even need the size as it has a constructor for just a `const char*`

Comment: Yes, but that constructor has to manually count the `char` elements. Since the source string already knows how many are present, it is better to pass that value to the constructor when it is known.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am always hesitant with that one as I can never remember if the size needs the null terminated size or not.  Just using the pointer only one stops me from having to worry.

Comment: The null terminator is *never* counted, not in the constructor, not in `size()` or `length()`.  If the string contains *embedded* nulls, those *are* counted, though, since they are character data. In which case, you *must* use the constructor that takes a count as input, otherwise they will be treated as a null terminator and won't be copied correctly.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks